# How to find point reflected over line in 3 dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, analytic-geometry

Find operator matrix of reflection over line x = 2y = z.
Can't find the reflected point, else should be easy

Comment: $\vec P'=2\vec n(\vec n\cdot\vec P) - \vec P$, where $\vec n$ is line unit vector.

Comment: Pretty much solved it. Thanks